# Node server code stuck in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've set up the code below on my node server in order to fill Event objects in my database with photos based on parameters sent to Instagram in a GET request through the API (latitude, longitude, distance, max_timestamp). My code pulls the first event from my database correctly, but then gets stuck in an infinite loop at the first console.log statement.

I'm seeing:
`sending request to Instagram for New Years Eve - Times Square with max_timestamp: 1419984000` logged to my console dozens of times in a matter of seconds. I'm not sure why the rest of my code is not running.

```
// modules =================================================
var express        = require('express.io');
var app            = express();
var port           = process.env.PORT || 6060;
var io             = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
var request        = require('request');
var Instagram      = require('instagram-node-lib');
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var db             = require('./config/db');
var Event          = require('./app/models/event');

// configuration ===========================================
mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our mongoDB database

// get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse         application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-  urlencoded

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method- Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location  /public/img will be /img for users


var baseUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=';
var clientId = MY-CLIENT-ID;

Event.find({}, function(err, events) {

  events.forEach(function(event) {

    var name = event.event;
    var latitude = event.latitude;
    var longitude = event.longitude;
    var distance = event.radius;
    var maxTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date(event.start).getTime()/1000);
    var endTimestamp = Math.floor(new Date(event.end).getTime()/1000);


  while (maxTimestamp < Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) && maxTimestamp < endTimestamp) {
    console.log('sending request to Instagram for ' + name + ' with max_timestamp: ' + maxTimestamp);
    request(baseUrl + latitude + '&lng=' + longitude + '&distance=' + distance + '&max_timestamp=' + maxTimestamp + '&client_id=' + clientId,
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { 
          console.log('error');
          return;
        }

          //JSON object with set of images
          var images = JSON.parse(body.data);
          var numImages = images.length;
          console.log(numImages + ' images returned with starting time ' + images[0].created_time + ' and ending time ' + images[(numImages - 1)].created_time);

            for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {

              //Save the new photo to DB
              Event.findOneAndUpdate( {latitude: latitude}, { $push: {'photos':
                { img: images[i].images.standard_resolution.url,
                  link: images[i].link,
                  username: images[i].user.username,
                  profile: images[i].user.profile_picture,
                  text: images[i].caption ? images[i].caption.text : '',
                  longitude: images[i].location.longitude,
                  latitude: images[i].location.latitude
                }}},
                { safe: true, upsert: false },
                function(err, model) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              );
              console.log(numImages + ' images saved to db');
            }
            maxTimestamp = images[(numImages - 1)].created_time;
            console.log('max_timestamp incremented to: ' + maxTimestamp);
          }
        );
      }    
    });  
});

// routes ==================================================
require('./app/routes')(app); // configure routes

// start app ===============================================
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
exports = module.exports = app;                         // expose app
```

Comment: Your `while` loop and inner `for` loop are calling asynchronous calls inside of them, but you are not waiting for the responses before moving to the next iteration. Look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for alternates that can use a callback to control iteration.

Comment: Very good point. Now that you bring that point up I may move my code to an Angular Controller and Service on the client side and update each event one at a time.

Comment: That is a **very bad** approach. But if you don't immediately know why it is bad to shuffle your logic to the "client" then perhaps you should ask an entirely different question.

Comment: Obviously shuffling this logic to the client permanently is a poor approach because I'll be exposing things such as my client_id. However, this is a one-time run to back fill past events for a web app that hasn't yet been released publicly.

Comment: Told you about [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) earlier. There are basically "drop in" (sort of, some editing) replacements for each of those keywords as mentioned. I'ts almost certainly less coding than making the client do the work. Anyhow, your loss if you can't take good advice.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Thought it may be quicker to use frameworks I already know rather than learning async. You're right though; that is the lazy, less efficient, and overall worse choice in the long run. Thanks again, I'll post my solution once I work through the async option.